# Is preventing $digest a bad thing?

Tags: angularjs

I'm making a task list in angular that looks like this

**Sortable list markup**

```
<ol>        
    <li><form id="task_creation_form"></form></li>
    <li ng-repeat="task in tasks">{{task.name}}</li>        
</ol>
```

As you can see, even the form can be dragged around and that causes my form to be positioned all over the place once changes to the `$scope.tasks` in my Controller are made, since that form is not part of the list

In order to walk around this, I ended up with this logic in my controller, that is fired every time a new task gets created, but before it gets added to the `$scope.tasks` array

```
$scope.$on('task_created', function(event, task){
        // Why the timeout?
        // When the task_created event is fired from the $scope, the tasks
        // property changes and the DOM get's updated. Thats is cool, but part
        // of the 'tasks' list, is the new task form that can also be reordered,
        // Therefore we need to detach it from the DOM, let the scope do it's digest and
        // reattach the form afterwards to it's proper position.
        // We wrap the entire thing in a setTimeout handler, so the $apply does not get 
        // automatically called and we force it to happen before re-attaching the creation form
        setTimeout(function(){
            // Tell the directive to detach the creation form (if it exists) so
            // it's position doesn't get messed up when the tasks array is applied
            $scope.$emit('detachCreationForm');

            $scope.tasks.splice(task.order - 1, 0,task);
            $scope.$apply();

            // Tasks are properly reordered. Tell the directive to reattach the creation form       
            $scope.$emit('reattachCreationForm');
        });
    });
```

Even though this works fine at the moment, I can't shake the feeling that something is completely wrong... Can this break my app in some way? Is it considered an ugly hack?

Comment: I am confused. Do you WANT the form in the <ol>? Why not just put it outside the ol if you want the position fixed?

Comment: I want it inside the <ol>, and I want it's position inside this <ol> to remain the same after changes have been made to the $scope.tasks controller property.